# How to access custom object in javascript module from another module?

Tags: javascript

i'm working on a project with pure JS and pure html. I have two html, in the first one, i create an avl tree with the correspondent javascript module for that html, but then, i want to access that same Avl tree from another JS module that is connected to the other html, is there any way to achieve this?

i have tried to export the tree, but i always get a new instance. I've also tried to create a function that returns this AVL tree but i get the same result. A new instance of the class AVL(). My last try was trying to save this object in localstorage, but it seems, localstorage can obly save string values, not objects. I am new to Js, so i would like to read your suggestions too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two separate HTML pages, `localStorage` would be the easiest solution. You can stringify your objects before placing them into `localStorage`.

On your first page you can do something like this to set the tree:

```
localStorage.setItem("avlTree", JSON.stringify(tree));
```

And on the second page you can do something like this to read it:

```
const tree = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("avlTree"));
```